# controlling list indexing

Tags: html, coding-style, html-lists

In html the list (ul and ol ) provides indexing  like

```
  1.main

    1.1 sub1
    1.2 sub2
       1.2.1 ....
```

i want indexing as

```
1. main
1.1 sub1
1.2 sub2

  how to do this
```

Comment: Can you post some example HTML or CSS (preferably both) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could put a style="display:block" into the <ol>,<ul>,<li> elements.

Regards.